# How to chain multiple columns with 'AND' addition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operator-keyword

I want to extract news by keyword and hashtags. In the keyword and hashtags, I want to combine them into 1 to create sentences in the form of strings using python.

Here's the table I have :

[image]

the desired output is like this
"Gempa AND #gempa cianjur AND #gempa bali" or "Lukas Enembe AND #lukas enembe tersangka AND #gubernur papua

Comment: df.agg(" AND ".join, axis="columns") probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apply on entire dataframe and join the column values  from each row. if you want your each row output as a string then use

```
df1[list(df1.columns)].apply(lambda row: f"'{' AND '.join(row.values.astype(str))}'", axis=1)
Out[145]: 
0           'Gempa AND #gempa cianjur AND #gempa bali'
1        'Fredy Sambo AND #fredy sambo AND brigadir j'
2    'Lukas Enembe AND #lukas enembe tersangka AND ...
```

**Without the quotes**

```
df1[list(df1.columns)].apply(lambda row: ' AND '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
Out[146]: 
0             Gempa AND #gempa cianjur AND #gempa bali
1          Fredy Sambo AND #fredy sambo AND brigadir j
2    Lukas Enembe AND #lukas enembe tersangka AND #...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Source**
Let's suppose we have the following dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Keyword': ['Gempa', 'Lukas Enembe'],
                   'Hastag1': ['#gempa cianjur' , '#lukas enembe tersangka'] ,
                   'Hastag2': ['#gempa bali' , '#gubernur papua']
                   })
```

Visualization:

```
        Keyword                  Hastag1          Hastag2
0         Gempa           #gempa cianjur      #gempa bali
1  Lukas Enembe  #lukas enembe tersangka  #gubernur papua
```

**Proposed script**

```py
df1['Chain'] = df1.agg(' AND '.join(['{0[%s]}'%c for c in df1.columns]).format, axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
        Keyword  ...                                              Chain
0         Gempa  ...  Gempa AND #gempa cianjur AND #gempa bali AND G...
1  Lukas Enembe  ...  Lukas Enembe AND #lukas enembe tersangka AND #...
```

**Alternative**

```py
df1['Result'] = df1['Keyword'] + ' AND ' + df1['Hastag1'] + ' AND ' + df1['Hastag2']
```